# How can I "copy" a query from a microsoft access database into an excel spreadsheet using microsoft vba?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

Hopefully the question I'm asking is clear and to be honest I'm also new to using Microsoft VBA (literally started trying to use it today). I'm trying to "grab" a query/data table from a Microsoft Access Database and I'm having difficulty understanding the syntax and exactly what commands do. At the moment it appears I'm getting into the query, but only returning the very first cell of the data table with the code:

```vb
Private Sub Select_From_Access()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim placementRange As Range

'DescriptionErrorByLot is the worksheet I want to put the table in, the range A1:Z44 is what would hypothetically be cleared
'if it needed to be once there is data there and needs to be updated
Worksheets("DescriptionErrorByLot").Range("A1:Z44").ClearContents

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'This is where I want the query (table) to be placed?
Set placementRange = Worksheets("DescriptionErrorByLot").Range("A1")

'Connection string containing provider and file path to the database
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\sjevne\Desktop\Database.accdb"

'Selecting the whole table from the query "jc_C2ComplaintCountbyLot10"? This is the queries name in the database
'To better explain what I'm talking about, there's buttons I can click on in the access database inside of the
'Reports section (click 'Reports' button) and then I click another button "Description errors by lot" and then
'A table/query with the name jc_C2ComplaintCountbyLot10 is open

strSql = "SELECT * FROM jc_C2ComplaintCountByLot10;"

cn.Open strConnection

Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

placementRange.CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Basically all I'm wondering right now is, what's actually allowing me to return the first cell in the data table I'm interested in? and how can I extend the range to grab the whole thing, obviously?
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

*EDIT 1* : Code

*EDIT 2* : I've been playing around with the code again, when I tried changing the SELECT * FROM to an existing connection that I was previously using to the database query that I want, and it said something about multi-valued cells and not being able to get data from a different database. (This connection to the worksheet was previously used to make an automated table, so as database table values changed, the spreadsheet did. All I'm trying to do now is just 'copy and paste' using a macro since the previous method is no longer available, sadly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the names are all being printed, but the only cell receiving a value is B2?

Comment: Not quite, so, the "jc_C2ComplaintCountbyLot10" is a query in the database. It's just a big table basically that I could just copy and paste manually but I can save time making a macro. What's happening when I press my nifty little button right now is, it only returns the very first cell in the table from the database into A1 on my excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I agree with Matt.

Comment: Alright, I deleted or at least commented out quite a bit of things that I originally had. Basically I made a string for the sql and connection path and also tried the rs = cn.Execute(strSql) , the code runs without errors but nothing is getting into my excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something similar grabbing the whole table, I do not bring in the field names they are already there.  Don't forget when you do this the IDs are coming with the table field data.

```
Private Sub getDataTable_Click()
    Dim conn As Object ' connection
    Dim rs As Object 'record set
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim placementRange As Range
```

'UPDATE THIS FOR YOUR WORKSHEET AND RANGE IF YOU WANT TO CLEAR BEFORE COPY

```
Worksheets("mtrInteraction").Range("I2:P25").ClearContents

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    'update this for the workbook,worksheet, and range where you want it
```

'UPDATE THIS FOR THE SHEET AND THE RANGE WHERE YOU WANT THE TABLE, UPPER LEFT CORNER

```
Set placementRange = Worksheets("mtrInteraction").Range("I2")
```

'UPDATE THIS FOR YOUR PATH AND DB NAME

```
'Build your connection and path
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\yourpath\yourpath\updatethis.accdb"
```

'UPDATE THIS FOR YOUR QUERY, TABLE NAME IS ALL YOU HAVE TO CHANGE TO COPY THE WHOLE TABLE, THE DB NAME IS SPECIFIED IN THE CONNECTION ABOVE

'Make your sql query to select all from YOUR table name

```
strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_MTR;"

    'open it you might want an error handler here
    conn.Open strConnection

    'get the recordset
    Set rs = conn.Execute(strSql)

    'copy your recordset in
    placementRange.CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is the same thing in a stub that has the field name you want and a data value in a cell for specific targeting:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
Dim fieldSTR As String
Dim placementRange As Range

Dim rs As Object 'record set

Dim conn As Object
Dim strQuery As String

Dim myDB As String

Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set placementRange = inputSheet.Range("E2")

fieldSTR = CStr(inputSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value) 'C3 cell
myDB = "C:\yourpath\yourpath\updatethis.accdb"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"    'For *.ACCDB Databases
        .ConnectionString = myDB
        .Open
    End With


strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & _
            "tbl_test WHERE Color = " & "'" & fieldSTR & "'" & ";"

'The below gives the same result as * but you could limit the fields returned as well
'tbl_test.ID, tbl_test.Color, tbl_test.number

MsgBox (strQuery)

Set rs = conn.Execute(strQuery)

placementRange.CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain to me what this line "Worksheets("mtrInteraction").Range("I2:P25").ClearContents" and this line " Set placementRange = Worksheets("mtrInteraction").Range("I2")" do? I tried to just use your code as a template basically whilst plugging in what I needed to change and I don't think the data from the query is getting to the spreadsheet.

Comment: sure the placement range is where I want the table copied into the worksheet "mtrInteraction", you will have a different worksheet name and likely want the upper left corner of the table to be somewhere else, change it accordingly.  The clear is just to clear that area prior, you may want a bigger range.  So I clear the range and then copy to that range.  That is it.  Clear and Copy the recordset.

Comment: I added some comments to the answer for you.  You have to update the path, the worksheet name, and your table name, and the placement range, you don't have to clear before copy but what if the data is a different size?  You will want to clear the a range first.

Comment: I've done all of that I believe, say my excel sheet is blank right now so clear contents would essentially be doing nothing, correct? The placement range is what I'm a little confused about still, how come it's just passing a cell and not a range (Range("I2"))? Is that just saying where you want the top left corner of the table to be placed? I'll repost my code if it helps, update rather.

Comment: If it is a blank sheet then no need to clear.  Just comment out that line with a ' and it won't be used. yes it is only specifying the top left corner anchor cell of the copy. Why?  This helps to avoid range size mismatches on copy paste, if you specify ranges and they are not the same size you get subscript errors, if their is data in your range you can get errors, this basically prevents a bunch of errors.

Comment: I dont mean to be confusing using only one cell and range, you could also call it placementCells As Cell and then use .Cells(1,1) this is Row/Col format with Cells, modify it for the cell you want, more understandable/readable to use the range and the Col name/Row number I think, you know exactly where the table copy anchor is going to be.

Comment: I updated my code, everything you're saying is making sense to me, was just making sure I had it right. Nothing's getting pasted into the spreadsheet I'm calling. With the code I had before, it would output the very first cell in the table I wanted, not the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, it's stripped bare so it may not compile cleanly:

```
Sub LoadRecordset(Sheet1 As Worksheet, query As String)
    Dim cnpubs As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cnpubs = New ADODB.Connection
    cnpubs.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=TESTDS;Database=TEST1;UID=sa;PWD=WERQEWDS"
    cnpubs.Open

    Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rsPubs
        .ActiveConnection = cnpubs
        .Open query
        fldCount = .Fields.Count
        iRow = 1
        Sheet1.Rows(iRow & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
        For iCol = 0 To fldCount - 1
            Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Value = .Fields(iCol).Name
        Next
        iRow = iRow + 1
        Sheet1.Range("A" & iRow).CopyFromRecordset rsPubs
        .Close
    End With
    cnpubs.Close
    Set rsPubs = Nothing
    Set cnpubs = Nothing

   Sheet1.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```